# How to clip features in 1 list to features in a 2nd list?

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, arcpy

I am a novice at geospatial coding. I have two lists made that contain 3 string items in each. I am working with the arcpy clip function and need to clip the items in list 1 by the items in list 2 using a for function. I cannot figure out how to call a variable in list one  and list two and then iterate the function to call the next variables.

I have tried defining new variables for the lists based on the variable created in the for statement.

```
lst1= ['boulder_OpenSpace.shp', 'lafayette_OpenSpace.shp', 'louisville_OpenSpace.shp']

lst2= ['sites53242bldBuff_3000.shp', 'sites430183lafBuff_3000.shp', 'sites329231louBuff_3000.shp']

for a in [range(len(lst1))]:
    town= lst1(a)
    buff= lst2(a)
    arcpy.Clip_analysis(town, buff,  'focused'+a)
    print(a, 'clipped to buffered sites')
```

I expect the function to select an item in list 1 and clip it to each item in list 2, then move on to the 2nd item in list 1 to again clip to each item in list 2. I am aware I am not close with this approach, but am having trouble figuring out where to start.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is for every town in list1, you want to clip it to each buff in list2.  That can be done with a nested loop or using a function in the `itertools` library.

#### nested loop

```
lst1= ['boulder_OpenSpace.shp', 'lafayette_OpenSpace.shp', 'louisville_OpenSpace.shp']

lst2= ['sites53242bldBuff_3000.shp', 'sites430183lafBuff_3000.shp', 'sites329231louBuff_3000.shp']

for t,town in enumerate(lst1):
    for b,buff in enumerate(lst2):
        output = "focused_{}_{}.shp".format(t,b)

        arcpy.Clip_analysis(town, buff,  output)
        print("{} clipped to {}'.format(town, buff)
```

#### `itertools.product()`

```
import itertools

lst1= ['boulder_OpenSpace.shp', 'lafayette_OpenSpace.shp', 'louisville_OpenSpace.shp']

lst2= ['sites53242bldBuff_3000.shp', 'sites430183lafBuff_3000.shp', 'sites329231louBuff_3000.shp']

for i,(town, buff) in enumerate(itertools.procduct(lst1, lst2)):
    output = "focused_{}.shp".format(i)

    arcpy.Clip_analysis(town, buff,  output)
    print("{} clipped to {}'.format(town, buff)
```